# How to define Severity in SNMP?

Tags: snmp

Hi I am trying to understand SNMP trap mechanism, I referred http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/snmp/ch02_06.htm#enettdg-CHP-2-TABLE-8.html and I understood that there are two types Generic and enterprise, Now In My Java code, I want to capture description from specific OID,

```
// variable binding for Enterprise Specific objects, Severity (should be defined in MIB file)
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("Major")));
```

Here, Instead of "Major", what should I specify to get the severity  for that specific OID?
Any help would be higly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In general, the severity is not an attribute of an SNMP trap.

Usually the custom severity mapping is defined in vendor specific MIB file as  variable binding of specific trap. Here is an example:

```
   sysLogMessageSeverity OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX  INTEGER {
           emergency (0),          --system is unusable
           alert (1),              --action must be taken immediately
           critical (2),           --critical conditions
           error (3),              --error conditions
           warning (4),            --warning conditions
           notice (5),             --normal but significant condition
           informational (6),      --informational messages
           debug (7)               --debug-level messages

       }
       ACCESS  read-only
       STATUS  mandatory
       DESCRIPTION
           "Severity level of the message"
   ::= { sysLogMibObjects 5 }
```

Please also note that most of modern NMSs allow the user to assign custom severity to any received SNMP traps based on user-defined rules.

The most widely used tool to do that is **NetDecision TrapVision**. Find out more at: http://netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1003

[image: TrapVision main application window]

Comment: "In general, the severity is not an attribute of an SNMP trap." - This is true for only one trap model which is 'Trap per event'. Some systems use single trap for many events while providing a lot of additional data, severity included.

Answer (score 2):

i used two ways before:
1. adding a severity variable to MIB and including it in any sent trap.
2. classifying events causing traps to Critical, Major, ... and assigning an enterprise trap id range to each type like: traps with ids in range (1,100) are Critical, traps with ids in range (101,200) are Major and...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please show me an example? after adding the severity level in MIB, How to use that in Java file?